# How to transfer a website from wordpress.com to a custom domain?

Tags: wordpress, web, blogs

One of my friends is facing an issue. He have a blog with wordpress `www.xyz.wordpress.com` and he want to convert it to `www.xyz.com` by purchasing a domain name with wordpress.

In this case, what would happen to his existing **RSS feeds** once the blog is transferred from `www.xyz.wordpress.com` to `www.xyz.com`? Will the **RSS Subscribers** be automatically upgraded? He have not burnt my feeds using `FeedBurner`.

Answer (score 0):

[Redirecting your blog from wordpress.com](http://support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/redirecting-your-blog/) with domain mapping.